# Splitting the frame with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I coded myself a weather app with python. When I run it with the command prompt, it works fine, as I want, without any problems.
Now I want to interface. But I can't say that I understand much about tkinter. I have looked at many tutorials, but I could not reach the result I want.

What I want to do is:

```
 _________________________________________
|                    |                    |
|    First Area      |    Second Area     |
|       Data         |        Data        |
|                    |                    |
|                    |                    |
|                    |                    |
|____________________|____________________|
|                    |                    |
|     Third Area     |    Fourth Area     |
|        Data        |        Data        |
|                    |                    |
|                    |                    |
|                    |                    |
|____________________|____________________|
```

Creating a 1000x750 window which is the easy part

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x750")
root.title('Hava Durumu')
root.resizable(0, 0)
```

I want to split this window that I created into 4. And pulling data from my app to each area (I guess fetching the data is ok too, i can do it :) )

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help with this.

Thanks

---Update---
I don't know which widget I should use.
for example

```
win = Tk() 
win.geometry("300x200") 

w = Label(win, text ='Bodrum', font = "90",fg="Navyblue") 
w.pack() 
    
msg = Message(win, text = "TEXT HERE") 
    
msg.pack() 

win.mainloop()
```

How do I put the result from my codes in "TEXT HERE" section?

Comment: This seems simple. Are you aware that you can organize multiple frames with `grid` into rows and columns?

Comment: I tried splitting with  `grid`. but I can't put my data with the properties (button, label etc) there.

Comment: Why can't you put your other widgets there? Please show us a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try splitting your `root` window into multiple `frames` first and then put your specific data in the appropriate frame. See this example

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk() 
root.geometry("200x200")

frame1 = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=1, relief='ridge')
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(20, 20), pady=(20, 20))
frame2 = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=1, relief='ridge')
frame2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(20, 20), pady=(20, 20))
frame3 = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=1, relief='ridge')
frame3.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(20, 20), pady=(20, 20))
frame4 = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=1, relief='ridge')
frame4.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(20, 20), pady=(20, 20))

w1 = tk.Label(frame1, text ='Bodrum', font = "90", fg="Navyblue")
w1.grid(row=0, column=0)
w1_1 = tk.Label(frame1, text ='35°C', font = "45", fg="Navyblue")
w1_1.grid(row=1, column=0)

w2 = tk.Label(frame2, text ='Berlin', font = "90",fg="Navyblue")
w2.grid(row=0, column=0)
w2_1 = tk.Label(frame2, text ='23°C', font = "45", fg="Navyblue")
w2_1.grid(row=1, column=0)

w3 = tk.Label(frame3, text ='Paris', font = "90",fg="Navyblue")
w3.grid(row=0, column=0)
w3_1 = tk.Label(frame3, text ='28°C', font = "45", fg="Navyblue")
w3_1.grid(row=1, column=0)

w4 = tk.Label(frame4, text ='Rome', font = "90",fg="Navyblue")
w4.grid(row=0, column=0)
w4_1 = tk.Label(frame4, text ='32°C', font = "45", fg="Navyblue")
w4_1.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Basically you create a `grid` in the `root` which can be filled independently from the `grids` of the `frames`. I put some spacer `padx` and `pady` between the `frames` and put a `border` around them to better visualize what the code is doing. Pay attention to the different locations where I create the `Labels`! So the `Labels` are part of the `frames`, which are part of the `root` window.
Consider checking some more tutorials, as this is very basic tkinter stuff.
I think [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQSEXcf6s2I&list=PLCC34OHNcOtoC6GglhF3ncJ5rLwQrLGnV) is explaining everything very nicely. Have fun.